# JavaScript code for a short computer task

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm very new to JavaScript programming and would appreciate any sort of help on this.

I'm trying to program a task that is separated into 4 games. Each of the games has the same structure- a stimulus (different image in each game) appears on the screen, then you have 2 choices- either 1) press “enter” to keep playing to see the “result” image (different image in each game) or 2) press “space bar” stop playing and accumulate the points earned up to that point. If you decide to keep playing, the “result” image will show up which will show you whether you win or lose one point. You start the game with 50 points and over 100 trials, the percentage of “win”s per 10 trials drops from 90% to 0%.

What is the best way to set up these trials and collect this type of data? Currently, I have made an array of 100 responses corresponding to the 100 trials:

```
correctresponse = [“spacebar_code”, “enter_code”, “enter_code”, “enter_code” ….]
```

Similarly, I’ve made an array of 100 outcome responses:
    outcome = [“image1.jpg”, “image2.jpg”…]

I’m also unsure as to setting up some key functions.  My function to capture keypresses right now is:

```
function getKeyTest(keyStroke) {
    isNetscape=(document.layers);
    keyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : keyStroke.keyCode;
    eventChooser = (isNetscape) ? keyStroke.which : keyID;
    which = String.fromCharCode(eventChooser);

    for (i=0;i<response_keys.length;i++) {  
        if (which == response_keys[i]) {    
            rtEndTime = new Date(); 
            var currentRT = rtEndTime - rtStartTime; 
            trialRTs.push(currentRT);

            if (currentRT < 500) 
                rtUnder500++;
            } else if (currentRT > 10000) {
                rtOver10000++;
            }

            if (response_keys[i] == correctResponses[trialNumber]) { 
                accuracy[trialNumber] = 1;
                correctTotal = correctTotal + 1;
            } else {
                accuracy[trialNumber] = 0;
            }

        trial_outcome();
    }

    if (which == spacebar_code && trialTypes[trialNumber] == "test") {  //this does not seem to end the trial   
        save_data(); }
    }
}
```

Another question I have is:

There are 4 different conditions that have to be randomized across the 4 games.

1. cue, delay;
2. cue, no delay;
3. no cue, delay;
4. no cue, no delay.

Where

- Cue = there’s a tally of points shown above the stimuli
- Delay = there is a 5-second delay between the outcome of each trial and the next chance for the person to respond

I’m not quite sure what the best way to randomize the 4 conditions across the 4 games would be.  I think I need to create an array and do a shuffle function, but how would I define the elements in that array to contain the two different aspects (cue and delay)?

Comment: Side note:  You appear to be missing two brackets in your code:  (1) the closing bracket for `if (which == response_keys[i]) {`, and (2) the opening bracket for `if (currentRT < 500)`.